# Количество миллисекунд между первым и вторым нажатием на кнопку

Tags: java, android, datetime

Как в android проще и лучше узнать количество миллисекунд между первым и вторым нажатием на одну и ту же кнопку?

Comment: Closure (Замыкания, Лямбда-выражения), можно с этим реализовать.
При первом нажатии (переменная`lastClicked == null`) записываешь в эту переменную текущее время (`lastClicked = timestamp`). При следующем нажатии выводишь разницу между текущим временем и `lastClicked`.

Comment: Для таймстампа использовать вот это? System.CurrentTimeMillis.

Comment: с кодом не смогу помочь, на java не кодил и не знаю всех тонкостей. В инете пишут что CurrentTimeMillis не может дать точное значение и выдаёт на разных процах разные результаты при вызовах (где-то всегда кратно 16мс выдает, где-то 1мс). Есть еще другие функции.. в общем экспериментируй)

Comment: Мне бы с точностью до 50 миллисекунд. А дальше пускай округляется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то так:

```
private long lastClickMillis=0L;

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton); 
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       long thisClickMillis=System.currentTimeMillis();
       Log.i("Timer", "Time elapsed since last click="+(thisClickMillis-lastClickMillis)
       lastClickMillis=thisClickMillis;
    }
});
```

**P.S.** Добрый я с утра, погода наверное хорошая...

Comment: глобальные переменные... опасный путь выбираете :)

Comment: @SultanovShamil а что тут опасного?

Comment: Это не глобальная переменная :), а переменная класса. К тому же вы наверное не знаете, что лямбда выражения всего лишь укороченная форма записи анонимных классов, в коих доступны лишь локальные переменные (значения которых не сохраняются), финальные переменные (которые нельзя менять) и члены класса.

Comment: переменная класса, которую спокойно может изменить другой метод этого же класса.. ) как работает лябда на джава - меня особо не волнует, я там не пишу)) а замыкание к нам пришло из функциональных языков, и текущую задачу можно решить с их помощью гораздо элегантней и безопасней имхо

Comment: @SultanovShamil - код в студию (на любом языке), иначе это просто бла-бла

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/91p0Lqwu/

Comment: Ну это практически то же самое. Разница в том, что `var start` у вас инициализируется в момент загрузки страницы. В Java это будет как внутренняя статическая переменная, `static long lastClickMillis=System.currentTimeMillis()` внутри `onClick()` - в каком то смысле это безопаснее, согласен.